# Grep filter not stop at first match

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep

I am trying to use

```
grep -o "javascript:add2BasketProd.*?jpg"
```

to extract string from

```
javascript:add2BasketProd('xKonfGFJsakj', 'Tattoo-Bubble-Gum-7cm-Bubble-Gum.jpg')Funny-Glasses-and-Teeth-Toy-Candy-TC-747-.jpg
```

but it would give no output. So I changed the code to the following but the output I get is entire string and not until the first match of `jpg`.

```
grep -o "javascript:add2BasketProd.*\?jpg"
```

My expected output is:

```
javascript:add2BasketProd('xKonfGFJsakj', 'Tattoo-Bubble-Gum-7cm-Bubble-Gum.jpg
```

Can anyone suggest a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`grep` uses POSIX style regular expression which are always greedy.  If your grep supports the `-P` flag, you can use it to enable perl style regex which do support non-greedy matches:

```
grep -oP "javascript:add2BasketProd.*?jpg"
```

The GNU `grep`, which is used on linux, supports `-P`.  The Mac OSX `grep` does not.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `egrep` for advanced regex capabilities:

```
s='javascript:add2BasketProd('xKonfGFJsakj', 'Tattoo-Bubble-Gum-7cm-Bubble-Gum.jpg')Funny-Glasses-and-Teeth-Toy-Candy-TC-747-.jpg'
egrep -o "javascript:add2BasketProd.*?jpg" <<< "$s"
javascript:add2BasketProd(xKonfGFJsakj, Tattoo-Bubble-Gum-7cm-Bubble-Gum.jpg
```

Comment: it still get all the string ,not at first match `jpg` .can you update it

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: It gives me output of `javascript:add2BasketProd(xKonfGFJsakj, Tattoo-Bubble-Gum-7cm-Bubble-Gum.jpg`

Comment: my expected output is `javascript:add2BasketProd(xKonfGFJsakj, Tattoo-Bubble-Gum-7cm-Bubble-Gum.jpg` ,i dont know why it get all the string in my result

Comment: That is exactly I am getting from above egrep.

Comment: i dont know why ,but i still get that result ,can you have any explaination

Comment: @anubhava This seems to work well on BSD `grep` but not with GNU `grep` which I believe OP is using. With GNU `grep` it defaults to greedy match using `?` and the only way to make it non-greedy is to use the `-P` option.

Comment: @JS웃 : it seems you right , i am using gnu grep ,thanks for explaination

Comment: Yes @JS웃 is absolutely right, I am using BSD grep since I am on OSX

Comment: @anubhava Its a bizarre behavior though. As far as I knew, non-greedy match was not part of BRE **and** ERE and that explains why it didn't work for OP with GNU `egrep`. Why it works on BSD `egrep` baffles me. Probable question on SO `;)`?

Comment: Yes I agree it was never part of ERE, not sure at what point BSD developers decided to start supporting it.